# SwiftUI: How to initialize Segmented Pickers from saved data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I save the selectedIndex of a few segmented pickers in UserDefaults when values change. I would like to restore these values to set the pickers when reopening the App.  The kicker is that these settings are used in several views and therefore the pickers are tied to @State variables.  State vars are immutable so my code:

```
    @State var abc:Int
Picker("Sort by", selection: $abc)
    let user = UserDefaults.standard
    $abc = user.integer(forKey: "abc")
```

I get the compile errors:

**Cannot assign to property: '$abc' is immutable**

**Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Binding'**

What is the way around this?

Comment: Use AppStorage , State should always be private. State are not immutable

Comment: I thought the point of State was to allow Binding elsewhere. I need a var in scope for the picker output.    Isn't AppStorage just a wrapper on User?

Comment: State is a source of truth with Storage within SwiftUI’s storage system that survives the lifecycle of a View. AppStorage is a source of truth with storage in UserDefaults. Both wrappers conform to DynamicProperty so they can trigger updates in a SwiftUI.View. Binding is a two way connection between a value type source of truth that conforms to DynamicProperty and a subview. DynamicProperty wrappers only work in a View, they can’t be placed anywhere else they require a View.Body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From iOS 14, there is a new way to do it called `@AppStorage`.

```swift
@AppStorage("abc") var selectedValue = 1
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

var body: some View {
    Picker("Select number", selection: $selectedValue) {
        ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) {
            Text("\($0)")
        }
    }
    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
}
```

Comment: Does this code fragment auto update the value of "selectedValue" in userDefaults storage?

Comment: Yeah, because it's binding the selected value to UserDefault storage and vice versa. You can test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Got it.  however, when I init the view containing the picker tied to the var in AppStorage, the picker does not change its selection. Is there a way to force the update of a picker to a new selectedIndex as there is in UIKit? How do I reference a picker in a view if it has no specific reference name?

Comment: You can set it normally as in UIKit, with the same key `UserDefaults.standard.set(3, forKey: "abc")`. They share the storage. Or split the view to a new branch, such as: `if hasKey { Picker with key } else { Picker without key }`

Comment: @BlueskyMed Use `.tag` for that, `Text("\($0)").tag($0)`

Comment: Thanks All, it works fine once i deleted some extraneous manual settings in UserDefaults.standard and let AppStorage do its thing on autopilot!

Comment: You're very welcome.