# Persisting CustomSegment Picker State in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have created a custom segment picker. Each segment has an index (of type int). I am persisting the state using UserDefault. So whenever the a different segment is click, the value is update. This works perfectly in maintaining state between different views. However, what is not working, when the app is closed and opened, I want a default segment to be selected instead of the last segment that was selected before the app closed.

Below is a snippet of the code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selSegmentIndex: Int = 1
    
    init() {
        if let savedSIndex = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "sIndex") as? Int {
            self.selSegmentIndex = savedSIndex
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
           CustomPicker(index: $selSegmentIndex)
              .onAppear {
                 if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "sIndex") != 1 {
                        selSegmentIndex = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "sIndex")
                 }
}
.onDisappear {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(selSegmentIndex, forKey: "sIndex")
}
```

Comment: Use AppStorage instead of State

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77482011/swiftui-how-to-initialize-segmented-pickers-from-saved-data) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: How to initialize Segmented Pickers from saved data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77482011/swiftui-how-to-initialize-segmented-pickers-from-saved-data)

Comment: @Sweeper No it doesn't, the last selected segment is persisted when the app is closed. When the app is reopened  the persisted state is shown.